# Trouble getting a PDF from a form with python Scrapy

Tags: python, pdf, scrapy, web-crawler

first of all, sorry if i did something wrong posting this but, em really new on forums, i've always managed to get my stuff done just by searching on google so im new to this stuff.

Well, there is this site: https://servicos.dpf.gov.br/sinic-certidao/emitirCertidao.html

I need to get the pdf that this site emits, to do so manually i have to fill only 3 inputs on the form, press "pesquisar" twice, fill the captcha and voila.

for example: 
nome: Werner Thomassen Andrade

Documento de Identificação: mg13905606

Órgão Emissor: ssp

press "pesquisar"
it will pop up a warning that we can ignore, just by closing it and then trying again

to do so on scrapy, im trying to use this (it's just the beggining of the code):

```
import scrapy
class aacRequest(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aacRequest'
    start_urls = ['https://servicos.dpf.gov.br/sinic-certidao/emitirCertidao.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'nome': 'Werner Thomassen Andrade', 'ci': 'mg13905606', 'orgao':'ssp'},
            callback=self.after_login)
    def after_login(self, response):
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            print "authFail"
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        else:
            print response
            print self
```

The thing is, its returning a link, that's the only response i get, and on that link there is a link to the form...
i'm really lost here, if you guys could help me that would be awesome
thx

Comment: For files like pdf you have to capture the file stream and dump it to a file.

Comment: thing is i didn't even got there yet

Comment: try setting a Firefox `user-agent` on settings, looks like the site only works with certain browsers.